# Python class returning value

Tags: python, class, return

I'm trying to create a class that returns a value, not self.

I will show you an example comparing with a list:

```
>>> l = list()
>>> print(l)
[]
>>> class MyClass:
>>>     pass

>>> mc = MyClass()
>>> print mc
<__main__.MyClass instance at 0x02892508>
```

I need that MyClass returns a list, like `list()` does, not the instance info. I know that I can make a subclass of list. But is there a way to do it without subclassing?

I want to imitate a list (or other objects):

```
>>> l1 = list()
>>> l2 = list()
>>> l1
[]
>>> l2
[]
>>> l1 == l2
True
>>> class MyClass():
def __repr__(self):
    return '[]'


>>> m1 = MyClass()
>>> m2 = MyClass()
>>> m1
[]
>>> m2
[]
>>> m1 == m2
False
```

Why is `m1 == m2` False? This is the question.

I'm sorry if I don't respond to all of you. I'm trying all the solutions you give me. I cant use `def`, because I need to use functions like setitem, getitem, etc.

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do? Why do you want to imitate a list? What is wrong with using an actual list?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If what you want is a way to turn your class into kind of a list without subclassing `list`, then just make a method that returns a list:

```
def MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value1 = 1
        self.value2 = 2

    def get_list(self):
        return [self.value1, self.value2...]


>>>print MyClass().get_list()
[1, 2...]
```

If you meant that `print MyClass()` will print a list, just override `__repr__`:

```
class MyClass():        
    def __init__(self):
        self.value1 = 1
        self.value2 = 2

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr([self.value1, self.value2])
```

EDIT:
I see you meant how to make objects **compare**. For that, you override the `__cmp__` method.

```
class MyClass():
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.get_list(), other.get_list())
```

Comment: That is the thing I dont want to do. I dont want to use mc1.getValue() == mc2.getValue(). I want to compare mc1 == mc2 without getValue. But ever says False

Answer (score 57):

I think you are very confused about what is occurring.

In Python, everything is an object:

- `[]` (a list) is an object
- `'abcde'` (a string) is an object
- `1` (an integer) is an object
- `MyClass()` (an instance) is an object
- `MyClass` (a class) is also an object
- `list` (a type--much like a class) is also an object

They are all "values" in the sense that they are a thing and not a name which refers to a thing. (Variables are names which refer to values.) A value is not something different from an object in Python.

When you call a class object (like `MyClass()` or `list()`), it returns an instance of that class. (`list` is really a type and not a class, but I am simplifying a bit here.)

When you *print* an object (i.e. get a string representation of an object), that object's [`__str__` or `__repr__` magic method](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#representations) is called and the returned value printed.

For example:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...             return "MyClass([])"
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return "I am an instance of MyClass at address "+hex(id(self))
... 
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> print m
MyClass([])
>>> m
I am an instance of MyClass at address 0x108ed5a10
>>>
```

So what you are asking for, "I need that MyClass return a list, like list(), not the instance info," does not make any sense.  `list()` returns a list instance. `MyClass()` returns a MyClass instance. If you want a list instance, just get a list instance. If the issue instead is *what do these objects look like when you `print` them or look at them in the console*, then create a `__str__` and `__repr__` method which represents them as you want them to be represented.

### Update for new question about equality

Once again, `__str__` and `__repr__` are only for *printing*, and do not affect the object in any other way. Just because two objects have the same `__repr__` value does not mean they are equal!

`MyClass() != MyClass()` because your class does not define how these would be equal, so it falls back to the default behavior (of the `object` type), which is that objects are only equal to themselves:

```
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> m1 = m
>>> m2 = m
>>> m1 == m2
True
>>> m3 = MyClass()
>>> m1 == m3
False
```

If you want to change this, use [one of the comparison magic methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#comparisons)

For example, you can have an object that is equal to everything:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...             return True
... 
>>> m1 = MyClass()
>>> m2 = MyClass()
>>> m1 == m2
True
>>> m1 == m1
True
>>> m1 == 1
True
>>> m1 == None
True
>>> m1 == []
True
```

I think you should do two things:

1. Take a look at [this guide to magic method use in Python](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/).
2. Justify why you are not subclassing `list` if what you want is very list-like. If subclassing is not appropriate, you can delegate to a wrapped list instance instead:

   ```
   class MyClass(object):
       def __init__(self):
           self._list = []
       def __getattr__(self, name):
           return getattr(self._list, name)

       # __repr__ and __str__ methods are automatically created
       # for every class, so if we want to delegate these we must
       # do so explicitly
       def __repr__(self):
           return "MyClass(%s)" % repr(self._list)
       def __str__(self):
           return "MyClass(%s)" % str(self._list)
   ```

   This will now act like a list without being a list (i.e., without subclassing `list`).

   ```
   >>> c = MyClass()
   >>> c.append(1)
   >>> c
   MyClass([1])
   ```

Comment: Link to http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html points to an expired/hijacked domain :( sad to see these days so many sites with great documentation are disappearing.

Comment: @n3storm Found another source for the magic method guide via the [Github issue](https://github.com/RafeKettler/magicmethods/issues/55) tracking the problem.

Comment: The rafekettler.com magic methods guide is still archived on the Wayback Machine / Internet Archive [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161024123835/http://www.rafekettler.com:80/magicmethods.html), also source on [GitHub](https://github.com/RafeKettler/magicmethods).

Answer (score 19):

Use `__new__` to return value from a class.

As others suggest `__repr__`,`__str__` or even `__init__` (somehow) CAN give you what you want, But `__new__` will be a semantically better solution for your purpose since you want the actual object to be returned and not just the string representation of it.

Read this answer for more insights into `__str__` and `__repr__`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19331543/4985585

```
class MyClass():
    def __new__(cls):
        return list() #or anything you want

>>> MyClass()
[]   #Returns a true list not a repr or string
```

Comment: Why it is a better solution?

Comment: Because you don't always need the string representation of an object to be returned. The use of `__str__` or `__repr__` will be wrong in that case. Of course you can use anything to return anything but `__str__` and `__repr__` are not made for that

Comment: Would it create new `list()` object all the time?

Answer (score 11):

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.value1 = a
        self.value2 = b

    def __call__(self):
        return [self.value1, self.value2]
```

Testing:

```
>>> x = MyClass('foo','bar')
>>> x()
['foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 4):

You are describing a function, not a class.

```
def Myclass():
    return []
```

Answer (score 0):

the worked proposition for me is `__call__` on class who create list of little numbers:

```py
import itertools
    
class SmallNumbers:
    def __init__(self, how_much):
        self.how_much = int(how_much)
        self.work_list = ['₀', '₁', '₂', '₃', '₄', '₅', '₆', '₇', '₈', '₉']
        self.generated_list = ['₀', '₁', '₂', '₃', '₄', '₅', '₆', '₇', '₈', '₉']
        start = 10
        end = 100
        for cmb in range(2, len(str(self.how_much)) + 1):
            self.ListOfCombinations(is_upper_then=start, is_under_then=end, combinations=cmb)
            start *= 10
            end *= 10

    def __call__(self, number, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.generated_list[number]

    def ListOfCombinations(self, is_upper_then, is_under_then, combinations):
        multi_work_list = eval(str('self.work_list,') * combinations)
        nbr = 0
        for subset in itertools.product(*multi_work_list):
            if is_upper_then <= nbr < is_under_then:
                self.generated_list.append(''.join(subset))
                if self.how_much == nbr:
                    break
            nbr += 1
```

and to run it:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
        sm = SmallNumbers(56)
        print(sm.generated_list)
        print(sm.generated_list[34], sm.generated_list[27], sm.generated_list[10])
        print('The Best', sm(15), sm(55), sm(49), sm(0))
```

result

```
['₀', '₁', '₂', '₃', '₄', '₅', '₆', '₇', '₈', '₉', '₁₀', '₁₁', '₁₂', '₁₃', '₁₄', '₁₅', '₁₆', '₁₇', '₁₈', '₁₉', '₂₀', '₂₁', '₂₂', '₂₃', '₂₄', '₂₅', '₂₆', '₂₇', '₂₈', '₂₉', '₃₀', '₃₁', '₃₂', '₃₃', '₃₄', '₃₅', '₃₆', '₃₇', '₃₈', '₃₉', '₄₀', '₄₁', '₄₂', '₄₃', '₄₄', '₄₅', '₄₆', '₄₇', '₄₈', '₄₉', '₅₀', '₅₁', '₅₂', '₅₃', '₅₄', '₅₅', '₅₆']
₃₄ ₂₇ ₁₀
The Best ₁₅ ₅₅ ₄₉ ₀
```