# Regex: Issues with parsing text in single quotes

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse the string enclosed in single quotes.

> For Input: Redditor(user_name='abc')
>
> My Output should be: abc

This is working as expected:

```
text = "Redditor(user_name='abc')"
author = re.findall(r'\'(.+?)\'', text)
print(author)
```

This isn't:

```
text = str(x.author) #I am getting x.author from API call. If I print x.author then it displays Redditor(user_name='abc') on the console so this is correct
author = re.findall(r'\'(.+?)\'', text)
print(author) #finds no match
```

Any ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: Because `x.author` is a `Redditor` instance, not a string, and that is just its `__repr__`esentation? Try using `repr(x.author)`, or probably `x.author.user_name` will save you the regular expression.

Comment: Have you tried `str(x.author)`

Comment: @MichalFrystacky note that the `__str__` may actually be different.

Comment: What does the API call return? Is it JSON or XML? You shouldn't need to parse an API response

Comment: @jonrsharpe repr(x.author) is working! thanks a lot! what exactly is the difference between repr and str? why didn't str work in this case?

Comment: And `.user_name`? I doubt you actually need to parse anything.

Comment: AttributeError: '<class 'praw.objects.Redditor'>' has no attribute 'user_name'

Comment: See [str() vs repr() functions in python 2.7.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331404/str-vs-repr-functions-in-python-2-7-5).