# What does `r` and `!` mean int python string?

Tags: python

I have following lines

```
{value!r}".format(value=value) 
%(access_token)r % value
```

What does `r` and `!` mean here?

Comment: That doesn't look like a legit (minimal) snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [conversion operation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). It converts `value` to a string using `repr()`

Check out "Explicit Conversion Flag" in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/ for more info.

Comment: what diffrence between str() and repr()?

Comment: Here's a description of the two. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331404/str-vs-repr-functions-in-python-2-7-5

Answer (score 0):

`r` means print the `repr()` of the object. `!` is what allows it to work in format strings.