# returning correct string format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to return `Col('red','blue',10)` but I keep getting `'Col(red, blue, 10)'` quotation marks are off.

Need to do this using formatting:

```
return 'Col(%s, %s, %d"%(col1,col2,total)'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> print "Col('%s', '%s', %d)" % ('red', 'blue', 10)
Col('red', 'blue', 10)
```

Comment: should just be Col('red', 'blue', 20), no end quotes!

Comment: I am trying to use repr("Col('%s', '%s', %d)" % ('red', 'blue', 10)) to return Col('red', 'blue', 10). This time. Any suggestions.

Comment: I don't understand. repr("Col('%s', '%s', %d)" % ('red', 'blue', 10)) already returns what you want...

Comment: It includes end quotes " ......." I don't want them. Is it possible to do this return function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331404/str-vs-repr-functions-in-python-2-7-5