# why "%" in python string invalidates the transfer character

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
t = ("rotation: %d%%\t [note]"% 123)
in jupyter notebook when you type t and run cell
output: rotation: 123%\t [note]
```

**I want to get result is follow here:**

output: rotation: 123%    [note]

Comment: No repro. There's no `\t` in my output.

Comment: Same here, where did you input this code to obtain the ``\t`` in the output?

Comment: when i print(t). there's no \t in output

Comment: Jupyter should use the `pprint` module to output the last return or value of a cell. `pprint.pprint("\t")` in fact gives you `\t`, which differs from a normal `print("\t")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a manifestation of jupyter notebook.  When using `str`, which `print` uses by default, we get

```
rotation: 123%   [note]
```

But when you type `t` into interactive python then [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#repr) is used instead.  It can be reproduced quite easily using any interactive python:

```
>>> t = ("rotation: %d%%\t [note]"% 123)
>>> t
'rotation: 123%\t [note]'
>>> print(t)
rotation: 123%   [note]
```

The difference is that `repr()` gives a representation of the object such that it can be recreated by code and is most useful for debugging.  `str()` (and `print`) gives a human (end-user) readable form.

See also:  [str() vs repr() functions in python 2.7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331404/str-vs-repr-functions-in-python-2-7-5) which also applies to python 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("rotation: %d%%\t [note]"% 123)
```

This should work